# How can I send an automatic email after a specific time period (mySQL datetime field)?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a field in mySQL database with a certain datetime.

If this datetime is exact 2 month ago from today, I want to send an automatic email, with a content like `"Hey, it is now 2 month ago, when this date was set"`

My question is, what is the best way to do it. I searched in the internet but only found something about cronjobs, but I think it is not the right thing in this case, because this datetime is set by the website user. Is this simply possible with php?

I am happy for any idea. Maybe you have expierience with this.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Cronjob is the way to go, just call a php script that checks the date.

Comment: Thank you, ah ok understand. You mean I call the script every day with cronjob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cronjobs is the best way. You can create job and set period to repeat. Cronjobs can be simple php script, sendEmail.php in which you select from DB content created 2 month ago and send users email with announcement.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will give it a try

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using Cronjobs or Daemon, however CronJob is better option. create a php file, in this file you will fetch only 2 month old content from mysql and send email to users.
and set Everyday cronjob for this file, This cronjob will execute your file every day and email will be sent to users if php file has any content created 2 months ago.